# How can I access a field in an array, where the name of the field in stored in a variable?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I have an array of type Records[], which contains fields such as name, age, and score.

I have a method which will be will need to access one of these fields, but I won't know which.

I want to, for example, do the following:

```
String fieldToUse = "name";
System.out.println(myRecords[0].fieldToUse);
```

In this case I could switch fieldToUse to whichever field I wanted to find. This doesn't work, however - how do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: myRecords is of type Records.

Comment: What is the type of `Records[0]`?

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected the post above. The array is called myRecords[] and is of type Records. Type Records includes a String and a couple ints.

Answer (score 4):

This could be done using refection:

```
Field field = Record.class.getField(fieldToUse);
Object fieldValue = field.get(record);
```

---

Full exeample:

```
static class Record {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    public Record(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Record[] records = new Record[2];
    records[0] = new Record("David", 29);
    records[1] = new Record("Andreas", 28);

    System.out.println("Davids name: " + getField("name", records[0]));
    System.out.println("Andreas age: " + getField("age", records[1]));
}

private static Object getField(String field, Record record) throws Exception {
    return record.getClass().getField(field).get(record);
}
```

prints:

```
Davids name: David
Andreas age: 28
```

Comment: How come getField is returning something based on getField? Wouldn't that throw it into an infinite loop?

Comment: It's a call to [`Class.getField(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29), not recursion.

Comment: @GuiR, both are different methods with different params.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need to do is impossible with Java.

With your structure, you should iterate over your `Records[]` and select the right one.

You may try using a `HashMap<String, Record>` where the `String` is `fieldToUse`.

This way you can just use something like `hashmap.get(fieldToUse)` to get the right `Record`

Comment: It's possible using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be to change the interface of `Records` to have a `getProperty()` style method:

```
System.out.println(Records[0].getProperty(fieldToUse));
```

Internally, `Records` could use a `Map` implementation to store the values. Assuming `name` is a `String`, and `age` and `score` are `Integer`s the `Map` would be `Map<String, String>`, keyed by the attribute name. Additionally, `Records` could provide methods for each attribute for use elsewhere that returned the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Map representation of type Record. With each field name as key.

```
Record
 name: "YXZ"
 age: 12
 score: 657
```

Now store this in an array.

You can now access

Records[0].get("name");

This is the best I can think of in terms of Java.

Comment: Not a very nice solution if you use field access in other parts of the program (then you would need to replace those occurrences with this type of accesses...).

Comment: Agree. If one has to keep the Record Object as is, then reflection will be a good idea as you mentioned in the other answer.